# Date format in quarters in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date-format

I am working in angularjs app and I am parsing dates depending of what period are selected in dropdown, for example for **"days"** and using:

```
{{mydate| date:'MMM/dd/yy'}}
```

for months:

```
{{mydate| date:'MMM/yyyy'}}
```

I there any way to format dates like **Q1/2016**?

I need pass this date format to google chart with config variable too.

**UPDATE**

If I use **'Q/yyyy'** for 10/01/2016 the results is 'T4/2016', why is added T to quarter number?

**SOLUTION**

**'Q/yyyy'**  working fine, the problem is with my google chrome language setting, that is in spanish and T is for "Trimestre", quarter in spanish.

Comment: I would use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

Comment: What represents Q1 ?

Comment: @HassanALi Q1 is a quarter 1 of 2016 for example, aditionally I need to use this format in google charts for all dates in hAxis in config variable like: {MyChrt: {format: 'dd/yy'}} for example but in Quarters

Answer (score 0):

If you use momentjs (which I highly recommend).

```
moment(mydate).utc().quarter();
```

Comment: This would just return `1`, which doesn't appear to be what the user wants.